# Telegram-bot пересылка сообщений себе в лс

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Вопрос на повестке дня такой: 
В боте будет что то на подобие заполнения анкеты, Например - Фио, дата рожд, номер телефона. После того как человек напишет все это, бот должен уже готовую анкету отправить в мои личные сообщения Telegram. 
И вот я не могу найти как это можно сделать, много уже где писал но так и ответа не нашел. Очень буду благодарен если на этом форуме помогут с этим. 
Заранее Спасибо !

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос говно

Comment: первая же ссылка в гугле https://qna.habr.com/q/929987

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам просто нужно в сообщении от бота указывать свой id в Telegram.

```
import telebot

token = 'Ваш токен'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

#Функция, которая выдаст ваш личный id
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def starter(message):
    print("Мой id: {}".format(message.chat.id)) #выведет в консоль ваш id при начале разговора
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Мой id: {}'.format(message.chat.id)) #пришлёт вам в сообщении id

#Функция, которая отправит инфу вам лично
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text_answer(message):
    bot.send_message(Ваш id полученный ранее, 'Ваш текст сообщения')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```